# DQ frame in foc of induction motor

Tags: motor, induction-motor, analysis

How to find the orientation of  DQ axis of rotor and stator in induction motor using iq and Id currents?

Particularly in foc of im, I have measurement of stator ia, ib, ic and rotor omega. However, rotor omega is not useful since rotor field and rotor spin asynchronously. At this stage, I can do Clark transform now. But how to get I'd and iq next?

Articles for these are not easy to obtain. It would be great if someone could link to reference articles.

Answer (score 4):

The DQ axis is not fixed with respect to any mechanical structure since the  stator and rotor magnetic fields rotate with respect to both the stator and the rotor.

Comment: I would like to find the rotating DQ frame axis. I know my alpha and beta axis. To perform SVM, I need to know DQ axis orientation with respect to alpha beta axis.

Comment: After I posted my answer, you revised the posting to delete the original question and replace it with a different question. That is not how this site works.

Comment: Sorry for not going by the norms.. I just thought the question needed elaboration so reframed it without realising that could affect your answer. Since I don't remember how I framed the original question now, I am unable to put it back now.